# Capture Japanese input in non-focused input element in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internationalization, keydown

When the user starts typing while the `<input>` element is not focused, I'd like user's input to go into the text input element. I achieve this by calling `$input.select()` in the keydown handler if the input is not already focused.

This works for English, but the Japanese input behavior differs between Chrome 44 and Firefox 39 (in OSX; I haven't tested in Windows). My goal is to achieve Firefox's behavior in Chrome.

**Repro steps**

1. Add Japanese input source in keyboard prefs, and then switch keyboard to Hiragana
2. Make sure the input is not focused
3. Type <kbd>e</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>

**Expected** *(works in Firefox but not Chrome)*

Input value is "えいご", allowing me to then select "英語" from the dropdown.

**Observed**

Input value is "eいご"

```js
$(function() {
    var $input = $('input:first');

    $(window).on('keydown', function(e) {
        if ($input.is(':focus')) {
            return;
        }
        $input.select();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer: It's a bug in chromium; impossible to fix as of Dec 2015.

Looks like it's related to this chromium bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=ime&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=551716.

There's a W3c draft API http://www.w3.org/TR/ime-api/ that could help, but looking at http://caniuse.com/#search=inputmethod it sounds unlikely that a solution could be built for a while.